# Android to C using NDK, then call Java functions in C

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

So, I am recreating a Palm Pilot program to run in Android. There is a library I have to continue to use written in C, but I am rewriting the UI components and the Bluetooth components of the application to run in Android. To initialize the device on the other end of the Bluetooth connection, I call `InitRelay` from the C code.

This is the original C code( no changes made yet ):

```
fp_setbaud RelayAPI_SetBaud;
fp_get RelayAPI_get;
fp_put RelayAPI_put;
fp_flush RelayAPI_flush;
fp_delay RelayAPI_delay;
fp_ProgressUpdate RelayAPI_ProgressUpdateTX;
fp_ProgressUpdate RelayAPI_ProgressUpdateRX;
...

BYTE __stdcall InitRelay(fp_setbaud _setbaud, fp_get _get, fp_put _put, fp_flush _flush, fp_delay _delay){

    RelayAPI_SetBaud=_setbaud;
    RelayAPI_get=_get;
    RelayAPI_put=_put;
    RelayAPI_flush=_flush;
    RelayAPI_delay=_delay;
    ...
}
```

The fp_* functions are typedefed in the `.h` file like this :

```
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_setbaud)(WORD);
typedef short (__stdcall *fp_get)(WORD);
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_put)(BYTE);
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_flush)(void);
typedef void (__stdcall *fp_delay)(WORD);
//typedef void (__stdcall *fp_err)(WORD);
typedef short (__stdcall *fp_ProgressUpdate)(WORD);
```

In the `main method` of the `old C program`, InitRelay() is called as follows :

```
InitRelay(Changeit,getit,putit,flushit,delayit);
```

The parameters are passed are functions defined in the main method. I have rewritten all of those functions in Java, and have created a new C method which looks like this :

```
jmethodID RelayAPI_SetBaud;
jmethodID RelayAPI_get;
jmethodID RelayAPI_put;
jmethodID RelayAPI_flush;
jmethodID RelayAPI_delay;
jmethodID RelayAPI_ProgressUpdateTX;
jmethodID RelayAPI_ProgressUpdateRX;
jclass    bluetoothClass;

BYTE __stdcall InitRelayJava( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj  ) {
    bluetoothClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass( env, obj );

    RelayAPI_SetBaud=(*env)->GetMethodID( env, bluetoothClass, "changeitJava", "(I)Z"  );
    RelayAPI_get    =(*env)->GetMethodID( env, bluetoothClass, "getitJava"   , "()V"   );
    RelayAPI_put    =(*env)->GetMethodID( env, bluetoothClass, "putitJava"   , "([B)V" );
    RelayAPI_flush  =(*env)->GetMethodID( env, bluetoothClass, "flushitJava" , "()V"   );
    RelayAPI_delay  =(*env)->GetMethodID( env, bluetoothClass, "delayitJava" , "(I)V"  );
    ...
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get thousands of errors about how all of my RelayAPI_* members aren't functions. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

I have also been told to add this function to create a JVM, but I really don't understand it at all....

```
JNIEnv* create_vm( JavaVM ** jvm ) {
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;

    JavaVMOption options;

    options.optionString = "-Djava.class.path=C:\\Users\\andrew\\workspace\\Singleton2\\src\\my\\eti\\commander";
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_7;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = &options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;
    int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM( jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args );
    if( ret < 0 ) 
        printf( "\nUnable to Launch JVM\n" );
    return env;
}
```

The tutorial that told me to write the function above is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI)...

So, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I assume that the `GetMethodID` call doesn't actually return the method itself....Does anyone know what else to do? I have been reading tutorials and there is something about a `CallVoidMethod` but I don't understand it...here is a link to a [tutorial](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html)...

Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a void method such as your `RelayAPI_flush` method.

If you have your Java class in the JNI as `jobject bluetoothClass` and you have acquired `jmethodID` of your method of that class by calling

```
RelayAPI_flush = env->GetMethodID(bluetoothClass, "flushitJava" , "()V");
```

you can then call the Java `flushitJava` function like this:

```
env->CallVoidMethod(bluetoothClass, RelayAPI_flush);
```

You probably will also have to attach/detach threads to/from VM correctly there are tutorials on the net regarding using JNI in Android.

For other methods we have in JNI according to http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/functions.html

```
Call<Type>Method
<NativeType>
CallVoidMethod
void
CallObjectMethod
jobject
CallBooleanMethod
jboolean
CallByteMethod
jbyte
CallCharMethod
jchar
CallShortMethod
jshort
CallIntMethod
jint
CallLongMethod
jlong
CallFloatMethod
jfloat
CallDoubleMethod
jdouble
```

Comment: And also, I am going to need to change some of my code but let me explain to see if you can help. RelayAPI_flush and the others are called hundreds of times throughout the rest of the library and I don't want to have to change them. So I will create methodIDs, but will have to set `RelayAPI_flush = env->CallVoidMethod(bluetoothClass, methodID)`. What type does that take on? I know its void, but I need to use it numerous times throughout my code in different functions so it must be a member.

Comment: Haha to add something else, this may seem like a stupid question but I have no experience in C, can I just declare something void?

Comment: @JuliCe For them there are corresponding fuctions such as CallIntMethod see here http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/functions.html

Comment: @JuliCe

You set RelayAPI_flush = env->CallVoidMethod(bluetoothClass, methodID) just once then keep your RelayAPI_flush  and use it in a CallXXXMethod as needed.


As to declare something void you can have a void function or a void* pointer. here maybe you will have to brush up your C++ just a bit, maybe not

Comment: OK well ignore that comment. When I am setting RelayAPI_flush in the InitRelay method, I am supposed to be passing it a function pointer. Does that make sense? I don't want to call the function just yet, but want to save it in my file so that I can call it later on in my code.

Comment: @JuliCe  You can do whatever you need to in your C code. You only need jmethodid s for those methodswhich are in Java so you can call them from C++. You can also pass a C++ pointer to Java as a jlong, keep it in Java and then send it back to C++ when you need to. Such as you can create a object in C++ take its address, pass it to Java,  then in Java you can pass it back to C++ cast it again to your native object so you can call a method for example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14464/discussion-between-juice-and-alex)